# How to binary read 7z archive

Tags: c++, 7zip, binaryreader

I need help for reading the number of files in the archive and their properties (weight, date etc). SDK can not be used. Only binary reading.

Comment: The complete file format specification (and therefore everything you will need) is contained in the `doc/` directory of the source archive.

Answer (score 1):

Read the source code for 7-Zip  and implement the parts you need. Here's the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/

Comment: do not tell me where it is being read from the file. the very first